# Access the ExternalAccessory API on OSX?

Tags: c#, macos, mono, xamarin, external-accessory

Going by [the Mono site](http://www.mono-project.com/MonoMac/Features), the externalAccessory API is available on Mono somewhere... but I can't work out what to include to get access to it from Xamarin.

I am working on Xamarin.Mac in C#.

What do I need to add to my project references, and what "using... " statement do I need, to be able to use the ExternalAccessory API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the ExternalAccessory API exist for OS X? I don't think so. The only references I can find from Apple discuss it as an [iOS framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ExternalAccessory/Reference/ExternalAccessoryFrameworkReference/_index.html).

Additionally, it is available in [Xamarin.iOS](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aMonoTouch.ExternalAccessory.EAAccessory) but not in Xamarin.Mac.

I suspect the reference to it on the page you cite is an error by copy-and-paste.